# Is there any way to upload a null value if the file field is empty and when its not empty, upload is value?

Tags: php, html, mysql, file, if-statement

First time here.

I'm trying to upload an image in a PHP form and when its empty, the value must be null.

I tried this code and it results when the file field is null! but when I upload some image, the result is double, one row with null value and another one with the file field value. Can i have some help?

```
    <?php
      if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
        $target_dir = "Uploads/";
        $target_file = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = pathinfo(PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $extensao = strtolower(substr($_FILES['file']['name'], -4));
        $novo_nome = $_POST['titulo'] . $extensao;
        $IsActive = $_POST['IsActive'];
        $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
        $descricao = $_POST['editor'];

        if($imageFileType != "jpg" || $imageFileType != "png" || $imageFileType != "jpeg" || $imageFileType != "gif" || $imageFileType != "docx" || $imageFileType != "doc" || $imageFileType != "html" || $imageFileType != "rar" || $imageFileType != "zip" || $imageFileType != "pdf" || $imageFileType != "xls" || $imageFileType != "xlsx" || $imageFileType != "xml" || $imageFileType != "psd" || $imageFileType != "svg") {
          if(!empty($_FILES['file']))
          {
            $sqli = "INSERT INTO `noticias` (Titulo, Descricao, IsActive) VALUES ('$titulo', '$descricao', '$IsActive')";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqli);
            if ($result) {
              echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=noticias.php'>";
            }
          }

          if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir.$novo_nome)) {
            $files = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
          } else {
            exit;
          }
        } else {
          echo "File Not Supported";
        }

        $location = '../bo/uploads/' . $novo_nome;
        $sqli = "INSERT INTO `noticias` (Titulo, Descricao, Imagem, IsActive) VALUES ('$titulo', '$descricao', '$location', '$IsActive')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqli);
        if ($result) {
          echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=noticias.php'>";
        }
      }
    ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to uodate an existing record, then you need to use an update sql statement and need to reference the primary key of that record. So, you probably need an edit form where you can select an existing record and change its contents.

Comment: Create two query texts - with `'$location'` insertion if it is not empty and with `NULL` if it is empty, and assign proper value to `$sqli` using `if(){}`.